# How to delete multiple parse users from an android app?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm making an android app that have 2 user types the first is an ordinary user that browses through news, the second type is  administrator that can add  news, edit them and delete.The admin can also add users and delete them .My question is about how can the administrator  delete a user or multiple users at the same time ???

Comment: What have you tried ? You should post some code or steps of what you have. Anyway, you should check ACL permission on the user table, Roles and ParseObject to see how you can pull this out.

Comment: Yes, an admin can delete multiple users or delete single user. Can you provide the code on where you are stuck at?

Comment: I haven't been able to write any code since i didn't found any methods on how i can delete multiple users and I'm new to parse so any help plz

Comment: i've been able to create the login/signup page and even allowed the administrator to add users but i started working on the delete user activity and im lost